# textSize gets scaled on droid but shouldn't be

Tags: android

I have specified textSize="3mm" but when I run the code on the droid the text is much smaller.  I looks like the size has been specified in px.  I am using minSdk=4 and anydensity = "true".  So it seems like if I ask for 3mm I should get 3mm, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Android recommends using sp (scale independent) units for text sizes.  [Linky](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

There were problem with the Droid display drivers reporting the wrong density. This made units like mm not work properly.